# A classic example is provided by a model solved rigorously by Smith four decades ago. - Is the use of "is" in this sentence correct?

Tags: tense

I am writing a scientific paper. Is the sentence below right in the tense?

> A classic example is provided by a model solved rigorously by Smith four decades ago.

The problem is, is the verb 'is' in contradiction with the 'four decades ago'?

Comment: I took it that the question was about tense, not number. And my answer is that the example exists now, so "is" is appropriate.

Comment: Think of it this way: The example **is** still valid and **does** still exist.

Comment: I posted the wrong comment. Sorry. "four decades ago" is modifying "solved" and it has nothing to do with the verb "is".

Comment: It seems correct to me. "A classic example is provided by a model (which is/was) solved rigorously by Smith four decades ago." . If you mean: a classic example is provided (by the writer/researcher) using a model which was solved...

Answer (score 3):

No, this is correct.

While the *study* **was conducted** long ago, this *classic example* **is provided** today.

The time frame of providing the example is current, right now, as you read it, so you use the present tense.

Comment: +1 Except among the radical literalists of the APA *Publication Manual*, texts which may be consulted in the present are deemed to "speak" to the reader in the present.